# WPF control that automatically shrinks content when content is larger than container

Tags: wpf, controls

Good morning,

I am creating a number of user controls in code on a WPF window.

is there a container control that I can add the usercontrols to that will automatically shrink the content to the size of the container.

I do not want the content to grow to the maximum available size only shrink uniform-ally.

I tried the stackpanel control in horizonal layout mode and whilst this seemed to be the way to go it only seems to overflow or clip the children (i.e scrollbars or hidden content off page).

what I need is for all of the content to be visible but resized once the maximum size is reached.

thanks in advance.

Dan.

Comment: from a user interface design point of view, this sounds like a bad idea

Comment: What about a [Viewbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms617883) with [MaxWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.maxwidth) and [MaxHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.maxheight)?

Comment: looking quickly online the viewbox only supports one child,  in answer to the ui design principles, this is not something that the user will interact with, its an array of user controls that are actually indicators, there will be between 1 and 16 but they need to display in a horizontal row and scale according to the space they have

Comment: Clemens, thank you, your answer bugged me as I was sure you would know that the viewbox only takes one control, so i re looked and the control, added a grid to it and it works .... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Clemens provided the answer in the comments but i cannot accept a comment as an answer so have posted it here.

the answer is to create a ViewBox and then put a container (containing all of the controls) in the viewbox.

this now shrinks and grows exactly as required and doesnt clip.

thanks

Dan.